# MUI: The `styles` argument provided is invalid. You are providing a function without a theme in the context

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am getting the below error when I tried to add a breakpoint in the navigation bar. I saw similar kinds of questions here but I am not able to sort out this issue. 
**Navbar.js**

```
import { AppBar, Toolbar, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import React from 'react';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
 logoLg: {
    display: 'none',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
        display: 'block',
    }
 },
 logoSm: {
    display: 'block',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
        display: 'none',
    }
 }
}));

function NavBar() {
const classes = useStyles();
return (
    <AppBar>
        <Toolbar>
            <Typography variant='h6' className={classes.logoLg}>
                Demo Page
            </Typography>
            <Typography variant='h6' className={classes.logoSm}>
                DEMO
            </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>
 )
}

export default NavBar;
```

**Packages**

```
"@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.5.0",
"@mui/material": "^5.5.0",
"@mui/styles": "^5.5.0",
```

[image: Error]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you wrapped your components inside a ThemeProvider anywhere?

Comment: @Erfan I have tried it in App.js file. But the issue hasn't been resolved.

Comment: Did you wrao your App with    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>  and did you pass your theme inside the Theme provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it in my local project. I found the same error when import it from "@material-ui/styles". Ant it works when I import it from core package.

import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

The useTheme function in "@material-ui/styles" doesn't return a default theme. I think it's the root cause.

I just test it in material-ui v4. Not sure it's also right in MUI v5.

The error occurs because MUI get a null theme from useTheme. So you should give it a valuable theme, maybe by themeProvider.

Comment: you save my day :). Thanks.